# Finished Render looks different from Preview

Tags: rendering

I have a scene of a tank firing confetti and the preview render looks normal.

[image]

However, when I render the animation, the entire confetti part stays at something that looks like this.

[image]

This is a motion track and the blurry streaks are still moving properly according to the camera movement. Is there any reason why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have `Motion Blur` enabled in the *Render Settings*. Motion blur is not currently supported in viewport renders, hence the confetti looking different in the final <kbd>F12</kbd> render.

To disable, simply un-check the box in the *Render Settings* tab:

[image: Motion Blur]

Comment: I had suspected motion blur for a little, but the streaks just stay there, they do not move at all. Is this because I didn't bake the particle system?

Comment: Never mind. It worked! Thank you so much!